# jpedal jpg2000 error

Tags: jai, jpeg2000, jpedal

I convert pdfs to images using jpedal. This works fine for most of the pdfs but some containing jpeg2000 i continue receiving the following error:

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: JPeg 2000 Images needs the VM parameter -Dorg.jpedal.jai=true switch turned on
    at org.jpedal.parser.PdfStreamDecoder.decodeStreamIntoObjects(Unknown Source)
    at org.jpedal.parser.PdfStreamDecoder.decodePageContent(Unknown Source)
    at org.jpedal.PDFtoImageConvertor.convert(Unknown Source)
    at org.jpedal.PdfDecoder.getPageAsImage(Unknown Source)
    at org.jpedal.PdfDecoder.getPageAsImage(Unknown Source)
    at com.....
```

I already set the JVM Parameter in the JAVA_OPTS, the run configuration of my tomcat and also in program code using:

```
System.setProperty("org.jpedal.jai", "true");
PdfDecoder decode_pdf = new PdfDecoder(true);
FontMappings.setFontReplacements();
decode_pdf.openPdfArray(pdf_file);
```

also the 3 JAI libs are on my build path.

So I don't know what else I have to do?

My complete code for the conversion is:

```
List<BufferedImage> images = new LinkedList<BufferedImage>();           
System.setProperty("org.jpedal.jai", "true");
PdfDecoder decode_pdf = new PdfDecoder(true);
FontMappings.setFontReplacements();
decode_pdf.openPdfArray(pdf_file);
decode_pdf.setExtractionMode(0, 1f); //do not save images
for (int i = 1; i<= decode_pdf.getPageCount(); i++)
{
  images.add(decode_pdf.getPageAsImage(i));
}   
decode_pdf.closePdfFile();
```

Any sugestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to this problem [here](http://tomcat.10.n6.nabble.com/Problems-with-ImageIO-td2073212.html).

When in a Tomcat environment you have to disable the JreLeakPreventionListener in server.xml then it works just fine.

Answer (score 2):

1. Activate jai for jpedal

   System.setProperty("org.jpedal.jai", "true");
2. A better solution (than the article from Mark Stephens blog) is to re-register the 
   provider, because this only has to be done once:

   IIORegistry registry = IIORegistry.getDefaultInstance();
       registry.registerServiceProvider(new com.sun.media.imageioimpl.plugins.jpeg2000.J2KImageWriterSpi());
       registry.registerServiceProvider(new com.sun.media.imageioimpl.plugins.jpeg2000.J2KImageReaderSpi());

Of course JAI libs need to be in the classpath to work correctly.